# Highlight specific element in an array -- PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Some of my code...

```
$a_array = array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 20);
$b_array = array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 20);

$a = $a_array[array_rand($a_array)];
$b = $b_array[array_rand($b_array)];

$a_multiples = array($a*1, $a*2, $a*3, $a*4, $a*5, $a*6, $a*7, $a*8, $a*9, $a*10);
$b_multiples = array($b*1, $b*2, $b*3, $b*4, $b*5, $b*6, $b*7, $b*8, $b*9, $b*10);

$result = array_intersect($a_multiples, $b_multiples);
$d = reset($result);
```

$d is the LCM of $a and $b (assuming it's in the first 10 multiples of $a and $b).   I then list out the first 10 multiples of $a and $b thusly...

```
echo $lista = implode(', ', $a_multiples);
echo $listb = implode(', ', $b_multiples);
```

How can I "highlight" (i.e. put in bold) the LCM in $lista and $listb?

Comment: use array_merge(),array_walk function to wirte the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using php 5.3 or above you can use a function to create a highlighter (closure) that can be passed to array_map:

```
 function highlighterGenerator($lcd){
       return function ($a) use ($lcd){
             return $a == $lcd?"<strong>".$a."</strong>":$a;
       }
 }
```

To use:

```
echo implode(", ", array_map(highlighterGenerator($d), $a_multiples));
echo implode(", ", array_map(highlighterGenerator($d), $b_multiples));
```

For older versions of php the following solution should be equivalent:

```
function highlighter($arr, $lcd){
     $ret = array();
     foreach($arr as $val){
          $ret[] = $val == $lcd?"<strong>".$val."</strong>":$val;
     }
     return $ret;
}
```

to use:

```
echo implode(", ", highlighter($a_multiples, $d));
echo implode(", ", highlighter($b_multiples, $d));
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in .....` which is the 2nd line of your function.  Typo maybe?

Comment: This format (closures) require php 5.3 ... I will update the answer to give you a different solution.

Comment: Wonderful!  It works now.  I also fixed the missing closing ) on the revised echos.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just try this (It's faster)

```
echo "<strong>" . implode("</strong><strong>", $a_multiples) . "</strong>";
echo "<strong>" . implode("</strong><strong>", $b_multiples) . "</strong>";
```

[**DEMO.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Godqk2)

Comment: nice explaination for understanding other

Comment: Thanks, just joining the array using `strong ` and the code describes itself, I think :-)